# How to check .txt file existence with TSQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SP reading a .txt file from File System and using Bulk Insert. I just wanna make sure if file exists before executing bulk insert command. How do i do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**try**

```
xp_fileExist ' <file Name> '
```

The above returns a result set.   If you want just a variable, use

```
declare @FileOK  INT

exec xp_fileExist 'c:\autoexec.bat' ,@FileOK OUTPUT

Print @FileOK
```

Comment: Just a note that this procedure is undocumented and unsupported, meaning tomorrow Microsoft could break it or remove it entirely, so use at your own risk.  There are also security concerns with opening up access to XPs for non-SA users.  Ideally this would be a good reason to introduce CLR functionality, which keeps you out of undocumented/unsupported territory, also gives you a lot more power and flexibility.